# PHP Wordwrap on an angle, increasing indentation each break

Tags: php, word-wrap

is it possible with php's wordwrap to add increased indentation each line break to essentially create wordwrapping on an angle?

Comment: What angle are you talking about? Are you talking about after specific number characters?

Comment: is the angle on the left or right?

Comment: the number of characters doesn't matter but if for example, you do the php wordwrap example `<?php
$text = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
$newtext = wordwrap($text, 20, "<br />\n");

echo $newtext;
?>` could each line break be indented on the left by a degree (pixel, percent, doesn't really matter).  so you'd end up having a paragraph that "wraps" on an angle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correcly, you would like to produce an output like:

```
xxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Obviously, replacing `x` with your text.

[`wordwrap`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) built-in function does not support this feature but you still can write your own, with a simple loop. Change the *max length* on each iteration, and break your initial string (depending on your needs, where you find a space or wherever you want).

Comment: yeah, i was thinking the opposite, so the angle is on the left, but yes that's the idea.

Comment: Then, decrease your line max-length on each iteration. It should be pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$text = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
echo $return = costomwrap($text , 10);

function costomwrap($text , $len)
{
$str = '';
for($i=0;$i<strlen($text);$i = $i+$len)
{
  $str .= substr($text , $i , $len ).'<br />';
  $len--;
}
return $str;
}

?>
```

live demo http://codepad.org/v3ysqV5A.
here, `<br />` not come on your programme.